# remote-true and js validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm using rails remote=>true for a Form , also I want to add some jquery validation.
I tried the following things, but they didn't work:

```
 $('form').live('submit',function(){

        alert('submit')
    })


    $('form').submit(function () {
           alert('subm')
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure the jQuery is finding your form? Have you put those functions within $(document).ready() or put the javascript after the form?

Comment: Yes I did the same.but I think due to remote=> true not let submit the form. that is the main issue probably.

Answer (score 1):

In order to validate a form using jquery, you should consider using the [jquery.validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin.

Example:

```
$('#someFormId').validate({
  rules: {
    someFieldId: {
      required: true,
    },
    someFieldContainingEmail: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
});
```

However, in your example code you've shown usage of the onSubmit event - you can validate this way as well. Example follows:

```
$('#someFormId').submit(function(){
  var someField = $('#someFieldId');

  if (someField.val().length < 2) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes I am using this so many places,But here rail automatically do the validation,Although above function is called when from get submit. But problem is that from is not getting submit because rails remote=>true send the form data using ajax ,Without submit the form.May be this will help you to get understand my problem.